# How can I find all possible values of $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{ax^2 - 1}{x - 1} = b$?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I am trying to tackle a "continuity"-related question that goes as

"Let $f$ be the function defined by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{ax^2 - 1}{x - 1} & \text{if } x \neq 0; \\
b & \text{if } x = 1;
\end{cases}
$$

Find all possible values of $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is continuous at $x = 1$."

I understand that for $f$ to be continuous at $x = 1$, its limit as $x \to 1$ has to equate its value at $x = 1$, that is
$$
f \text{ continuous at $x = 1$} \longleftrightarrow \lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = f(1).
$$

Hence, the equation
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{ax^2 - 1}{x - 1} = b
$$
needs to be true.

This is where I'm stuck. I know that I need to factor out the denominator $(x - 1)$ so that I may be able to evaluate the limit through direct substitution, but obviously I can't directly factorise the numerator as it is - I understand that I am lacking the knowledge of some property.

As this is a past exam paper, I referred to the answer key, and it says:

"In order for $f$ to be continuous at $1$, $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$ must first exist (not be infinite). This forces the numerator to be zero:
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} ax^2 - 1 = 0.
$$

Hence,
$$
a - 1 = 0 \text{ or } a = 1."
$$

So, another question I have is, why is the numerator "forced" to be zero for the limit to exist at $x = 1$?

Thank you so much for reading. I would be sincerely grateful to anyone who is able to help.

Comment: If  numerator is not zero as $x$ approaches $1$ then limit will not be finite. For limit to exist it must be of form $0/0$

Comment: Thanks for the response. Why will the limit not be finite if the numerator is not zero? And why must it be of the form $0/0$ for it to exist?

Comment: Your approach/idea is correct and based on $\lim_{x\to 1}ax^2-1=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{ax^2-1}{x-1}\cdot(x-1)=b(1-1)=0$. Use limit laws at first, they are much more powerful, but unfortunately their power is not so much advertised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need for continuity that limit exists finite, then we need, as a *necessary condition*, that numerator also goes to zero at $x=1$

$$\lim_{x\to 1} ax^2-1 = a(1)^2-1=a-1=0 \implies a=1$$

therefore numerator must contain $(x-1)$ as a factor such that

$$\frac{ax^2 - 1}{x - 1} =\frac{x^2 - 1}{x - 1}=\frac{(x+1)(x - 1)}{x - 1}=x+1 \to 2$$

finally we need to set $f(1) = b =2$.

Refer also to the related

- [Find $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{ax^6+bx^5+1}{(x-1)^2}$ is finite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3080663/505767)
- [Find $a,b$ such that $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\frac{a}{x-3}-\frac{b}{x}}{x-1}=4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3388973/505767)

---

Note that the condition that numerator goes to zero at $x=1$ is just a *necessary condition* but, in general, it is not a *sufficient condition*.

Let consider for example

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{ax^2-1}{(x - 1)^2} $$

in this case also we need $a=1$ as a necessary condition but

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2-1}{(x - 1)^2}=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x+1}{x - 1} =\pm \infty$$

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the response. Does it suffice to say that, for $ax^2 - 1$ to contain an $(x - 1)$ factor, then $a = 1$? I can see how that is the case, but am struggling to take that as it is.

Comment: @SamuelYap Asnoticed, the key point is that if $ax^2-1 \to c\neq 0$ we can't have a finite limit, therefore we need $a=1$ as a condition, that is the numerator must contain a factor $(x-1)$.

Comment: Got it. I will refer to the two posts that you linked to get a better understanding. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can I ask why the numerator must also go to zero? Is there some lemma/theorem of some sort? I can see how when $c \neq 0$ we can't have a finite limit, as the limit will just shoot off to $±\infty$, but my question now is all because $c \neq 0$, why must $c = 0$? Is it just because $c$ can't take on any other value than $0$? So, it "defaults" to $0$?

Comment: @SamuelYap We have two scenarios. The first one is $ax^2-1 \to c\neq 0$ and in this case limit is not finite since denominator goes to zero. The second one is that $ax^2-1 \to 0$ in this case overal limit has a chance to exist, it is a necessary condition but not suffcient.

Comment: I see that makes a lot of sense. I will take that as it is, it makes intuitive sense. If you do have an example of a scenario where the limit doesn't exist after setting the numerator to 0, I would love for it. Else, you've helped me a lot already, and I am really grateful. I will set your response to the selected one.

Comment: @SamuelYap I've added an example where we apply the necessary condition but the limit doesn't exist finite.

Comment: Alright thanks so much! Yeah that makes sense. If the denominator still isn't able to be cancelled out, then there will still remain a 0 there. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

You may write

$$\frac{ax^2-1}{x-1}=\frac{(a-1)x^2}{x-1}+x+1$$

For the limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{(a-1)x^2}{x-1}+x+1$$ to exist, you need $a=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $\lim_{x \to 1} ax^2-1 = c \neq 0.$ Then you would have that $$\lim_{x \to 1+} \frac{ax^2-1}{x-1}=\frac{c}{0+} = \pm \infty \not\in \mathbb{R},$$ where it is $+$ if $c >0$ and $-$ if $c<0.$

That is why you have that $a=1.$ Now you evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\lim_{x \to 1} x+1 = 2,$$ so $b$ must be equal $2.$

Comment: Hi V.J., thanks for the response. Your response gave me the intuition to see how if $a^2 − 1 \neq 0$, the limit cannot be finite. However, now I am struggling to understand how, $a^2 − 1 = 0$ helps the limit become finite.

Comment: You think $a-1=0?$ See the second part of previous answer. If $a=1,$ you have ax^2-1=x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1).$

Comment: Sorry typed wrongly. Missed out the $x$. Thanks.